# C sharp Access data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

Используется код для выборки всех колонок в таблице и дальнейшее применение к каждой функционала update. При этом он на колонки типа integer как я понимаю выдаёт `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` . Как проверить тип данных до произведения запроса?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + tb_tablename.Text, conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }

                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    {
                        if (column.ColumnName != "ID1" && column.ColumnName != "ID" && column.ColumnName != "Geometry" && column.ColumnName != "Geometry_SK")
                            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE " + tb_tablename.Text + " SET " + column.ColumnName + " = Replace([" + column.ColumnName + "], Chr(10), \"\");", conn))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                    }
                }
```

Проверка (column.DataType is string) не отрабатывает. При этом если сделать вывод типа - встречается Int32. Как проверить тип корректно?

Нашёл как проверить корректно `if (column.DataType == typeof(String))` но ошибка осталась. С чем может быть связана данная ошибка?

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."
```

Генерируемый запрос без проблем выполняется в самом Access.

Вынос запроса не помог.

```
string query = "UPDATE [" + tb_tablename.Text.Trim() + "] SET [" + column.ColumnName + "] = Replace([" + column.ColumnName + "], Chr(10), \"\");";

                            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
```

Comment: Не нужно вот так задавать аргументы, используйте параметризованные запросы. И заодно почитайте про экранирование.

Comment: Зачем вы тут используете `using` ? У вас что там `IDisposable` в `OleDbDataAdapter`, нет, ну а зачем тогда вам `using`?